# Execution of Apex class using Bulk of Records

Tags: apex

For a Single Record apex class:

```
public class myControllerExtension {

    private final Account acct;

    public myControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {

        system.debug(stdController);
        this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
        system.debug(this.acct);
    }
    public String getGreeting() {
        return 'Hello ' + acct.name + ' (' + acct.id + ')';

    }
}
```

In Developer Console:

```
Account acc = [select Id,name from account limit 1]; 
ApexPages.StandardController stdController = new   ApexPages.StandardController(acc);
myControllerExtension  ext = new myControllerExtension (stdController );
ext.getGreeting();
```

How to pass Morethan one Records in Developer Console

Comment: Could you explain a bit more ?

Comment: How pass above developer console like:

Comment: list<Account> acc = [select Id,name from account limit 3];

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish by doing this? I have a feeling you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: @sfdcfox i Want for bulk of Records using Standard Set Controller for Bulk of Records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you couldn't pass more than one record before is that constructor for the ApexPages.StandardController class can only take a single sobject as input. Here is a list controller version of what you wrote:

```
public class myControllerExtension {

    private final list<Account> acctlist;

    public myControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController stdSetController) {

        system.debug(stdSetController);
        this.acctlist = (list<Account>)stdSetController.getRecords();
        system.debug(this.acctlist);
    }
    public list<String> getGreetings() {
        list<String> greetings = new list<String>();
        for (Account acct : acctlist) greetings.add('Hello ' + acct.name + ' (' + acct.id + ')');
        return greetings;
    }
}



list<Account> acclist = [select Id,name from account limit 3]; 
ApexPages.StandardSetController stdSetController = new   ApexPages.StandardSetController(acclist);
myControllerExtension ext = new myControllerExtension (stdSetController );
ext.getGreetings();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try do something like this:

```
List<Account> accList = [select Id,name from account]; 
for(Account acc: accList){

    ApexPages.StandardController stdController = new   ApexPages.StandardController(acc);
    myControllerExtension  ext = new myControllerExtension (stdController );
    ext.getGreeting();
    system.debug(':::'+ext);
}
```